# Illegal slot:Illegal binding in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am getting this error message while sending my array to intent. My array read like this

```
var result = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:{d:5,e:6,f:7},
  x:3,
  y:4,
  z:9
}
```

This is the structure and now I am getting the error

```
Value Compilation Error: EmptyOptionalValue
IllegalSlot:illegal binding 'd' for '1.0.3-myApp.api.C': ./c
IllegalSlot:illegal binding 'e' for '1.0.3-myApp.api.C': ./c
IllegalSlot:illegal binding 'f' for '1.0.3-myApp.api.C':
```

Comment: Can you show me the model for your expected output? It will help me to see what Structure this result is supposed to represent.

Comment: As per your question, it triggered to me that first i need to create inner structure and then need to assign it to the parent.. So i fixed it. You answer it standard and i will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it is resolved!

Comment: Have posted one more question and also have given my capsule diagnosis report.. please look into it

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to a mismatch between the Structure model defined to represent this array and the `result` being returned by the Action Javascript.